# Using ROW_NUMBER In WHERE Clause

Tags: java, sql, derby

I am trying to retrieve a string value based on currentQuestion integer. However I read in documentation that ROW_NUMBER cannot be used in WHERE clause with Java Derby. Are there any other functions available that allow me to filter results based on row number? I have written this so far, though I get error on the getQuestion string.

```
public String getQuestion(int currentQuestion) throws SQLException {
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

        String getQuestion = ("SELECT QUESTION FROM GAME_TABLE WHERE ROW_NUMBER = ?");
        PreparedStatement preStatement = connection.prepareStatement(getQuestion);
        preStatement.setString(1, Integer.toString(currentQuestion));
        ResultSet resultSet = preStatement.executeQuery();

        System.out.println("Question " + Integer.toString(currentQuestion) + " retrieved.");

        return resultSet.getString(1);
    }
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: You can use a `CTE`, Or subquery

Comment: `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "=" at line 1, column 50.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Statement st = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
 String getQuestion = ("SELECT QUESTION FROM GAME_TABLE ");
 ResultSet resultSet = st.executeQuery(getQuestion);
 resultSet.absolute(currentQuestion);// moves the cursor to the row
 return resultSet.getString("Question");
```

Ofcourse this answer will is like processing after getting the entire table

Comment: Hey thanks for that, getting an error on line `no suitable method found for createStatement(int)`. The error only appears when I add ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE to the connection line.

Comment: Hey thanks for the edited code, createConnection method does not exist. I will try search that up a bit more, thank you :)

Comment: sorry, can you check it now with updated.. it will work

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CTE` like:

```
WITH CTE As(
SELECT QUESTION, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Arguments you want) As RN
FROM GAME_TABLE
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = ?;
```

Or, a subquery like:

```
SELECT T.*
FROM ( SELECT QUESTION, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Arguments you want) As RN
FROM GAME_TABLE ) As T
WHERE T.RN = ?;
```

Comment: Thank you, I gave that a go, and resulted in `java.sql.SQLException: Invalid cursor state - no current row`. Is that because I provided no arguments in the Over() function parameter?

Comment: @TheChosenOne You have to use arguments, Like `OVER (order by ID ASC)`

Comment: Derby does not support common table expressions and it doesn't support an `order by` in `row_number()`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name He can use subquey